# Abstraction layer between Controller and View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, architecture

I am trying to create another layer between my controller and my view so that I can pass different versions of a view to a user based on their "client ID" which would be the company to which they belong.

I have the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // set client
        var client = new Client();
        client.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        client.Name = "Foo";

        // set user
        var user = new User();
        user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        user.ClientId = client.Id;
        user.Name = "Foo";

        return ViewRenderer.RenderView("AddComplete", client);
    }
}
```

My ViewRenderer class looks like this:

```
public static class ViewRenderer
{
    public static ViewResult RenderView(string view, Guid clientId)
    {
        string viewName = GetViewForClient(view, clientId);
        return Controller.View(view);
    }

    public static string GetViewForClient(string view, Guid clientId)
    {
        // todo: logic to return view specific to the company to which a user belongs...
    }
}
```

The problem is, the line `return Controller.View(view);` in `RenderView(string view, Guid clientId)` gives me the error:

> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View()' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

I am interested to know how I can resolve this error or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do, which is to display different versions of a view which are specific to the respective company to which a user belongs.

**Edit:** Another option I was kicking around in my head...

Is there a way to override the `View()` method such that I can prepend it with a directory name, for example, a user who belongs to "Acme Co." would call the same controller action as everyone else like `View("MyView")` but the method would actually be calling `View("AcmeCo/MyView")` however, I don't actually write that code in my controller, it's just derived from the user's client ID property.

Comment: The Controller.View() method is protected. You can't access the protected method unless you derive your viewrender from controller.

Comment: @MichaelG Thanks but even when I do `public static class ViewRenderer : Controller` it still gives the same error.

Comment: When using the derived class, remove "Controller.", and use base.View(view);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View()` method is a protected member. You can only access it from within a derived type, such as your `HomeController` class. Plus you're trying to access it as a static method.

You can create a base Controller that exposes your specialized view logic. For the sake of illustration, I'm going to call it DynamicViewControllerBase

```
public class HomeController : DynamicViewControllerBase
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // set client
        var client = new Client();
        client.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        client.Name = "Foo";

        // set user
        var user = new User();
        user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        user.ClientId = client.Id;
        user.Name = "Foo";

        return RenderView("AddComplete", client);
    }
}

public class DynamicViewControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected ViewResult RenderView(string view, Guid clientId)
    {
        string viewName = GetViewForClient(view, clientId);
        return View(view);
    }

    // Unless you plan to use methods and properties within 
    // the instance of `Controller`, you can leave this as 
    // a static method.
    private static string GetViewForClient(string view, Guid clientId)
    {
        // todo: logic to return view...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mario, I was thinking about something like that.

Comment: +0: @user1477388 Note that as Mario J Vargas noticed in first half of the answer the code in extension sample *will not compile* because `View` is protected method. Consider just mapping view name (like `return View(ViewMapper.Map("myView", clientId))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just replace the view engine instead of adding another abstraction.

Write your own View engine (here is how to start off with a RazorViewEngine)

```
public class ByIdRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
   protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        string viewPath, string masterPath)
{
    var id = // get something from controller context controllerContext
    var newViewPath = CalculateViewPathFromId(id);

    return base.CreateView(controllerContext, newViewPath, masterPath);
}
```

And register it in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ByIdRazorViewEngine());
}
```

Comment: I really like this idea.  I don't know how much work this is, though.  Also, not sure how easy it is to get to `HttpContext` so that I can retrieve the current user's ID and do a database call to get their client ID property.  Any thoughts on that part?

Comment: ControllerContext has the RequestContext on it, you might want to get the client Id with an async filter if you have database access involved

Comment: Thanks for that idea.  However, when I google `async filter mvc` it says that MVC doesn't have such a filter (though Web API does).  Can you show me any links to this idea?

Comment: Darn, you are right. No such thing... (I was thinking MVC vNext). I suggest you do it sync, unless you have super high scale site, you won't notice a difference. Alternatively you might be able to capture this as part of your authentication/authorization and just use it in the viewengine

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to have is the company name prefixed to your controllers, apply the `RoutePrefix` attribute on to your controller.

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix(@"{company}")]
public partial class HomeController : Controller 
{


}
```

And in your RouteConfig file,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Make sure this line is added
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

}
```

Since your users must be authenticated to sign in to their accounts, once they've authenticated them selves you can either:

- Store a cookie on your users machine with the name of their company
- Make calls to your database on each request to retrieve this information
- Make use of ViewData[]
- etc..

Once you have the name of their company, you can construct the urls with that name.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    // ... authenticate user etc

    // Redirect to 
    // foo.com/abc/home
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { company = "abc" });
}
```

If you're trying to work a way around this, I doubt you'll be able to as the web request first comes through a route, and the route decides which controller/action is executed, but to know the company name your action needs to execute to retrieve.